# How can fix "number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length"?

Tags: r

I have' done as below R code. 
However,the message "number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length" appear.

How can I fix the problem? Thank you for your advice in advance!!

```
irtp <- function(t1, t2, a1, a2, b, c, pexp) {
  d <- -b*sqrt(a1^2+a2^2)
  pexp <- c+(1-c)/(1+exp(-((theta1*a1)+(theta2*a2)+d)))
  return(pexp)
}

###set seed for randdon number  
seed<- 98765432
set.seed(seed, kind = NULL, normal.kind = NULL)

### Number of examinee
N <- 1000

### Number of items
kitem <- 20

### Simulate latent trait scores ~ N[0,1]
theta1 <- rnorm(N, 0,1)
theta2 <- rnorm(N, -0.5, 1)

alpha1 <- runif(kitem, 0.2, 0.5)
alpha2 <- runif(kitem, -1, 0.5)
beta <- rep(0.8, kitem)
guess <- rep(-0.5, kitem)

#setup matrix 
P <- matrix(nrow=N,ncol=kitem)

for(i in 1:N){
  for(k in 1:kitem){
    P[i,k] <- irtp(theta1[i], theta2[i], alpha1[k], alpha2[k],
                   beta[k], guess[k], pexp)
  }
}
#print(P)
```

Comment: Why `irtp` has the `pexp` argument when in the body it's overriding its value? When you call `irtp` in the loop, you pass the `pexp` object which you didn't define and so the base function `pexp` is passed. More: you have the `t1` and `t2` arguments in `irtp` and in the body you use `theta1` and `theta2` instead.

Comment: If you try and run your `irtp` call with, say, N=1 and k=1, you'll find it returns 1000 values. You obviously can't fit 1000 values in one matrix cell.

Answer (score 0):

That means the length of **P** doesn't fit to the new P from the function.  You should change the parameter to match the one within the function.

```
  irtp <- function(**theta1, theta2**, a1, a2, b, c, pexp) {
  d <- -b*sqrt(a1^2+a2^2)
  pexp <- c+(1-c)/(1+exp(-((theta1*a1)+(theta2*a2)+d)))
  return(pexp)
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your advice. it does do well!!